# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes before login screen

Tags: freeze

I am having issues with my dual boot. Ubuntu freezes on the loading screen with the dots (before it asks you to log in).

I dont know how to remove resolve this. I have booted in safe mode and can view my files.

Any ideas? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried to boot through upstart (chosen in grub), login through Ctrl+Alt+F1 and start lightdm manually?

Comment: I will give that a try

Comment: When booted through upstart, it freezes at

Comment: Loading initial ramdisk

Comment: I believe the issue has been caused by trying to install gnome

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons and solutions for this.

**1) Removing quiet splash**

When you are on the grub menu (the menu which you select what OS to boot), make sure that your selection is on "Ubuntu" and press E. You'll see a line like this one:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

And remove "quiet splash". To save grub like this, press F10.

**2) nomodeset**

If the first one doesn't work, after deleting "quiet splash", add "nomodeset" in their place. If this works, it also means that you probably have nvidia GPU or Dual GPU.